# Wrong alignment of navigation bar button for second view controller in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar, ios13, uinavigationitem

I am adding a button using the storyboard as below screenshot:

[image]

While presenting from 1st controller to 2nd controller, navigation bar button alignment is not displaying properly.

[image]

I don't know whether it's iOS 13 problem or what.

Comment: share your navigationBar item code please

Comment: @elia I am adding a button using the storyboard. Updated my question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this issue, you need to call setNeedLayout manually in the viewWillAppear method as mentioned below:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)
     if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
          navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()
     }
}
```